# Is it possible to withdraw the suggested edit?

Tags: support

I edited one question. For some reasons i want to **withdraw** that edit suggestion while it is in the queue for review. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Short answer: no. You'll have to wait for it be either approved/rejected. I'm curious - how have you ended up making a suggested edit that you'd rather withdraw anyway?

Comment: @JonClements : Actually i edited this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9266047) . Before it actually reflects , someone edited it. Now the only difference b/w my edit and the question is extra lines in between rows. Obviously it will be rejected. So  I want to withdraw it and dont want to increase my rejected count. Won't it be better if we have some options to withdraw in these cases?

Comment: @Crazy2crack the occasional rejected edit isn't going to cause any harm - heck - even perfectly valid edits get rejected on occasion. It's not a big enough of a thing to warrant any system changes really, so if it is rejected, just don't worry about it.